# A permutation problem, select even number of balls

Tags: permutations, combinations

I’m trying to solve the problem:

There are n kinds of ball, that each kind of balls are countless. How many ways are there to select an even number of balls of each type, a total of l, and arrange them?(There may be balls of an unselected type.)

My thought: Using inclusion-exclusion principle. But It was so complicated to calculate it.

Actually, the answer is $\frac{1}{2^n}$$\Sigma_{i=0}^{n}$$_n C_i (n-2i)^l$
But i couldn’t reach the answer.

Help me please.

Comment: If $l$ is even, the formular is 1.

Comment: Very good point.  I totally overlooked that.  I have deleted my comment.